# Abstract meaning of internal hashing

Tags: database, hash

Good morning everybody
I am trying to understand hashing techniques but getting blocked in those points
What is meant by internal hashing? Is hashing within the buffers of the main memory?
The hashing is done automatically by the system or we have to apply? if we have can someone put me in the beginning of the path?
Thank you all

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: 1. what is the difference between internal and external hashing

Comment: also need to know how can implement them? is it through a programimg language ?